# I have to call an api if focusout, for multiple dynamic fieldset which holds input text area

Tags: jquery, angularjs

> I will have a plus button, on clicking the button fieldsets will be created with two input text areas in it.
> my task is to call API if focus lost from the current field
> Here the problem is since multiple dynamic fieldsets are created, Id cannot be taken since fieldsets will have the same ID(which will not be unique).
> Not only the fieldset but also the input field id's
> And I tried to give Id unique by adding an index to it but I could not use
> the Id in Jquery.

```
<fieldset class="mb-10 col-md-8" style="padding:10px 0;" id="dbcrFieldsMultiple{{$index}}"
ng-repeat="entries in vm.dbcr.dbcrMultipleEntriesDetails">
<div class="col-md-1" ng-hide="true">
<span class="serial-number">{{ $index + 1 }}.</span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
<label>Input Stream Name
<span class="requiredField">*</span>
</label>
<md-dialog-content>
<div class="md-dialog-content;padding: 10px;">
<textarea ng-model="entries.dbcrInputStream" id="InputStream" press-enter- 
key="vm.initiateIndex($event,$index,entries.dbcrInputStream,'INPUT_STREAM')" value= 
{{entries.dbcrInputStream}} class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter Input Stream Here"> 
</textarea>
</div>
</md-dialog-content>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
<label>Fallback Stream Name<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
<md-dialog-content>
<div class="md-dialog-content;padding: 10px;">
<textarea ng-model="entries.dbcrFallbackStream" id="InputStream_fallback_{{$index}}" press- 
enter-key="vm.initiateIndex($event,$index,entries.dbcrFallbackStream,'FALLBACK_STREAM')"
class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter Fallback Stream name Here"></textarea>
</div>
</md-dialog-content>
</div>
<div class="fContent col-md-1" ng-if="vm.dbcr.dbcrMultipleEntriesDetails.length > 1">
<br>
<button plan-action-control action="delete" ng-click="vm.removeEntries(entries)" 
style="background: #F44336 !important;color: #eee !important;" class="btn btn-xs">
<md-tooltip md-direction='top' class="actionButtonTooltip">Delete</md-tooltip><span 
style="font-size: 12px;"><em class="fa fa-trash"></em></span></button>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

> Jquery I tried if the focus is out of text area of a fieldset

```
setTimeout(function(){
$('#dbcrFieldsMultiple').focusout(function(){
alert("yes")
})
$('#InputStream').focusout(function(){
alert("yes")
})
})
```

Comment: Maybe you have to do this with angular itself. See here: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/angular-input-focusout-event-exampleexample.html

Comment: This is angularjs and ng-focus or ng-blur is not working as expected and if i give ng-blur="callMyFunction($event)" inside input field then whever getting into the input area my menthod is called.but i dont want that instead, whenver the focus is out of the field alone the menthod shuld called

Answer (score 0):

Why use jQuery? Angular does things a whole different way. It doesn't need element IDs (but you really shouldn't be duplicating element ID's). just call the native `ng-blur` event

```
<fieldset class="mb-10 col-md-8" style="padding:10px 0;" id="dbcrFieldsMultiple{{$index}}" ng-blur="onInputBlur($event)" >
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-

In the controller

```
$scope.onInputBlur = function (e) {
   // element: console.log(e.target);
}
```

Comment: I dont want ng-mouse ovr / ng-mouseout if the focus removes from the area then i need to call the function

Comment: @User_01 - I misunderstood. ng-blur is what you want, and you can access the element in the blur handler if you need it. That way if there is a certain element you want to apply logic to in this way, you can test for it in the blur handler. I updated my answer